# A word for "want" without the connotation of desire or need?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which would be able to express a will to do something without the desire or need to do it? Is it even possible have a word for doing something without referring to either of these aspects?

Comment: You could do things *randomly, aimlessly*. But otherwise it's surely through *necessity* (meeting internal needs, or complying with external duress), or simply *desire*. I can't really think of any real-world context where you have a ***will/wish*** to do something without there being some kind of *desire* or *need* involved. Please clarify.

Comment: Desire and need are pretty much the meaning of want

Comment: Maybe [*"RNA **lacks** the base thymine"*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zzOyVeidAvP88wfX77LgDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22RNA+lacks+the+base+thymine%22), if we assume RNA is incapable of experiencing desire, and doesn't actually "need" anything.

Comment: For example: the actions undertaken by a personified ('sentient') machine - it neither desires or needs to do something yet does it anyway.

Comment: Another example could be: following the will of god/king - someone may neither desire or need to follow his will yet does it out of a sense of duty (i.e. purpose).

Comment: Like, as in "I'd like a week off."  This certainly doesn't imply need.  As for desire, it implies only a mild desire.  You can't want something without some level of desire for it, unless you are a Vulcan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Intend](https://www.google.com/search?q=intend%20definition)**

> verb
>   1. have (a course of action) as one's purpose or intention; plan.

(Google)

or **[Purpose](https://www.google.com/search?q=purpose%20definition)**

> verb formal
>   1. have as one's intention or objective.

(Google)

I think these don't imply either a desire or need. A robot might intend or purpose to do something just because it was programmed.

Comment: @Tarius both are verbs: I purpose to have some dinner (it's usually pronounced slightly differently as a verb)

Comment: Just deleted my comment as soon as I realised my mistake (before I saw your reply). Never knew "purpose" could be used in that context, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a quick question: how is purpose pronounced when used as a verb?

Comment: @Tarius to rhyme with prepose: pur-pose (rather than pur-puss) (I believe)